# Извлечения двух символов из строки

Tags: java

Есть строка String a. В ней какой то набор цифр с пробелами. Нужно чтобы программа брала первые 2 числа, и помещала их в другую строку. После я сравниваю с заранее известным алфавитом из одной и двух цифр это значение. После процесс повторяется и полученные значения я вывожу через массив строк. Меня конкретно интересует процесс извлечения двух символов из строки.

Comment: вам нужно смотреть в сторону `StringTokenizer` или `Scanner` (если строка до этого считывается из консоли)

Comment: StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead.

Comment: спасибо, давно мануалы не читал

Answer (score 4):

Предположим, что строка выглядит так:

```
String str = "1 2 3 4";
```

Можно воспользоваться методом [split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) примерно так:

```
String[] tmp_arr = str.split(" ");
```

Соответственно первые два элемента массива tmp_arr будут первые два числа в строке.

P.S. 
Java очень плохо знаю. Возможно можно более изящно решить вашу задачу.

Comment: А можно узнать, как конкретно этот метод работает?

Comment: @Omfis, метод split принимает разделитель, с помощью которого он(метод) будет делить строку на несколько элементов. Этот метод вроде даже может принимать на вход регулярное выражение. Это на случай если числа в строке разделены одним и более пробелами или другими символами.

В моем примере разделить это пробел. 

Если вы имели ввиду как работает этот метод изнутри, то я, к сожалению, не знаю(

Comment: А может быть так, что он помещает разделенную строку в массив не String,a char?  Если это так, то я незнаю как сравнивать 2 элемента массива char со одним элементом массива String.

Comment: я не очень понял о чем вы. метод split возвращает массив строк.

Comment: Просто я думал сравнивать полученное значение из строки с алфавитом при помощи switch. поэтому и думаю, как все значение вместить в 1 переменную.

Comment: ничего не пойму. Что вам сейчас мешает сравнивать с помощью switch?

Comment: Ну я же не могу целую строку сравнивать с алфавитом, в котором по 1 или 2 цифре. Тем более мне нужно чтобы они выводились в особой упорядоченности. Если это вам поможет, то я провожу синтаксический анализ заданного фрагмента методом рекурсивного спуска и составляю кодировочную таблицу. С радостью выслушаю другие способы реализации.

Comment: метод split принимает не разделить, а регулярное выражение. Поэтому, если хотите, что бы разделителем выступала точка, то: str.split("\.");

Answer (score 2):

Почему бы цикле по длине строки не извлекать символы, и записывать в отдельную переменную пока не встретиться пробел, как вы получите две цифры производите свои вычисления. Далее продолжаете считывать строку посимвольно.

Comment: Можно попробовать...

Comment: А почему никто не плюсусет? Чисто сишный ответ в Java, бывает редко.

Comment: в чужой монастырь со сишными правилами не ходят =)

Comment: почему правила?! уже наверное все варианты перебрали - мой один из вариантов. У задачи порой бывают несколько вариантов решения, и все они правильные, а эффективность это уже другой вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

```
new String().substring(0,2);
```

Comment: Не подходит. Строка длинная, и очень долго высчитывать координаты для каждой подстроки. Тем более что может идти символ из одной цифры, а такого нет в алфавите ,потому что взяли еще и следующую за ней.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 0,
        first = 0,
        second = 2;
String str = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 11 12 13 1",
        sub_str = null;
String str_without_separator = str.replace(" ", "");
System.out.println(str_without_separator);
while(i != (str_without_separator.length()/2.0)){
    try{
    sub_str = str_without_separator.substring(first,second);
    } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        sub_str = str_without_separator.substring(first,str_without_separator.length());
        System.out.println(sub_str);
        break;
        }
    first += 2;
    second += 2;
    System.out.println(sub_str);
    i++;
}
```